# CakePHP – How to not violate MVC or DRY in this situation

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a controller (for my main page) in which I have about 5-6 actions which renders the same view (index), because user may choose different params on the page for different situations. Each action handles each situation.

Now I need to display latest news on my main page. Looks simple...
So I added

```
$this->set('fetchednews', $this->News->getLatestNews());
```

to my index action and it works as it should be.

But as I said before I have a set of different actions with the same view for this page.

So if user goes to domain.com he see latest news, but if user clicks link e.g.

```
domain.com/mainPageController/sortById/1
```

he didn't see latest news because

```
action sortById
```

didn't have  $this->set('fetchednews', $this->News->getLatestNews());

Should I use Elements and in an Element use

```
$news = $this->News->getLatestNews();
```

and then use this element in the index view? Or I need to repeat

```
$this->set('fetchednews', $this->News->getLatestNews());
```

to each action I add to my main page controller?

How to properly handle this situation?

Comment: How about using a `beforeFilter`, assuming all actions need to set `fetchednews`?

Comment: This is a nice suggestion. I'll try it right now, thanks.

Comment: @MattHuggins thank you, this is what I looked for. Please post your suggestion as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a [`beforeFilter`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/984/Callbacks), assuming all actions need to set `fetchednews`?

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->set('fetchednews', $this->News->getLatestNews());
}
```

Comment: You should use beforeRender() for setting view vars not beforeFilter();

Comment: Good call ADman, I forgot CakePHP allows this.  I've been using Rails for too long now :)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd wrap up all the functionality that needs to be shared into a new method which takes in your controller as a parameter, then performs the common actions. You'd still need a call from each action that required the news, but at least you could modify it/add additional code in a single place...

I'm not familiar with Cake as I tend to use CI myself but something like...

```
function MyAction1() {
    //Other code
    $this->CommonCode();
}

function CommonCode() {
    $this->set('fetchednews', $this->News->getLatestNews());
}
```

or if you'd prefer to move the function outside your controller (to avoid it being interpreted as an action itself), pass the controller into the method...

```
function MyAction1() {
    //Other code
    CommonCode($this);
}

//Different class
function CommonCode($controller) {
    $controller->set('fetchednews', $this->News->getLatestNews());
}
```